# Constraints not centering views on phone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-constraintlayout

I'm having a weird bug. I really don't know why.

So, on the editor, my constraints work just as I want. But on the phone, they don't.

Pictures (I don't have enough reputation to show images..):

[android studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FTZhR.png)

[phone problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y5nBo.png)

Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        tools:context=".fragments.home.HomeFragment">

        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="some text"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="some text"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/textView2"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</layout>
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind, just found the problem.

Both width and height need to be `match_parent` on the `NavHostFragment` in `activity_main.xml`.

```
<!-- navigation fragment -->
<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/navHostFragment"
    android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
    app:defaultNavHost="true"
    app:navGraph="@navigation/navigation"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the ConstraintLayout height to "match_parent"?
It seems like you restrict it to the combined height of the TextViews.

Also, you shouldn't set BottomToTop and TopToBottom in such a way, one should depend on the parent. You can easily do it by selecting both views in the editor, right clicking the choosing `Chain Vertically`.